# ValueError: too many values to unpack python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for

estaba haciendo un script en python y tiene un for que tiene a m y n con el valor de materias (var m) y notas (var n)

pero me sale este error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "materias.py", line 11, in <module>
    for m, n in materias, notas:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

este es mi codigo:

```
materias = ["Ed. fisica","Matematica","C.Sociales"]
notas = []


for i in materias:
    print(f"cuanto te sacaste en {i}")
    x = input()
    notas.append(x)


for m, n in materias, notas:
    if 7 >= n:
        print(f"desaprobaste en {m} porque te sacaste un {n}")
    print("aprobaste")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios errores:

- El ciclo `for m, n in materias, notas:` no itera a la par sobre las dos listas, solo itera sobre `materias` realmente. Esto es lo que causa el error mostrado ya que solo tienes un valor en cada iteración e intentas desempaquetar en dos variables (`m` y `n`). Para solucionarlo debes usar `zip`:

  ```
  for m, n in zip(materias, notas):
      ...
  ```
- Estás agregando a la lista notas cadenas (que es lo que retorna `input` en Python 3). No puedes comparar una cadena con un entero, por lo que la línea `if 7 >= n:` te generará una excepción de tipo `TypeError`. Debes convertir a `int` o `float` de forma explícita (dependiendo de si las notas pueden contener o no decimales):

  ```
  x = float(input())
  ```
- El bloque:

  ```
  if 7 >= n:
      print(f"desaprobaste en {m} porque te sacaste un {n}")
  print("aprobaste")
  ```

  hace que siempre se imprima `"aprobaste"` en todas las iteraciones, se ejecute o no el `if`. Debes meterlo dentro de un `else` para que solo se ejecute cuando el `if` no se cumpla.

El código debería quedar:

```
materias = ["Ed. fisica", "Matematica", "C.Sociales"]
notas = []

for materia in materias:
    x = float(input(f"¿Cuánto te sacaste en {materia}?\n"))
    notas.append(x)

for materia, nota in zip(materias, notas):
    if 7 >= nota:
        print(f"Desaprobaste en {materia} porque te sacaste un {nota}")
    else:
        print(f"Aprobaste {materia} con un {nota}")
```

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en la parte del for, se está iterando dos por lo que tendrías que agregar la función `zip()`. El propósito de `zip()` es mapear el índice similar de múltiples contenedores para que puedan usarse simplemente usando como entidad única.

```
for m, n in zip(materias, notas):
print(m)
if 7 >= int(n):
    print(f"desaprobaste en {m} porque te sacaste un {n}")
print("aprobaste")
```

Saludos!